# make find search in alphabetical order

Tags: shell, find, date, sort, cat

I am currently using a short find command in order to search a number of directories (and sub-directories) for files ending in "tex" and then catting them into one coherent text. The command that I Use is this one:

`find . -name '*.tex' -exec cat {} \; > blub.txt`

However, the find command doesn't search the folders the way I would want them to do it. It jumps around a lot and instead of first grabbing the folder "2011" it begins with "2013" etc. Is there a way of amending that, so that it begins with 2011, and the subdirectories therein, i.e., with the folder "01-january", then "02-february" etc.

Comment: How many levels of directories do you care about ordering? Just the 2, year and month?

Comment: Does the shell matter here? bash and zsh have extended globbing facilities; are you in an environment that supports them?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have too many total directories, you could force `find` to traverse the paths in order by giving them all at the command-line:

```
shopt -s globstar
find **/ -name '*.tex' -exec cat {} \; > blub.txt
```

(Using bash syntax for enabling the recursive `**` glob). The glob expands in naturally sorted order, so the years would sort first, then each of the numerically-prefixed months would sort inside each year. The trailing slash asks bash to only return directories, letting `find` find the files.

Alternatively, if you have a list of years as subdirectories, you could loop over that:

```
for year in *
do
  find "$year"/* -name '*.tex' -exec cat {} \;
done > blub.txt
```

This expands the 12 months of each year into each loop, again forcing `find` to process them in order.

Comment: If `globstar` already does the work for you, can you simply `cat **/*.tex`?

Comment: Excellent point! I "thought" myself into a corner of using `find`, but -- you're right!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might work:

```
find -type f -name \*.tex -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 cat >> blub.txt
```

The `print0` option for `find` uses a `NUL` character to delimit found objects, which can be leveraged with `sort -z` to put them into lexical order; we then feed that ordered list into `xargs`.

Comment: With —null for xargs

Comment: `sort` is not returning null-delimited output though; see `echo -e "b\0a" | sort -z`.

Comment: interesting!? while testing, I ran `find * -print0|sort -z|od -c` and saw nulls between the filenames

Comment: @DopeGhoti Try it with three values: `echo -e "b\0a\0c" | sort -z`. The newline ends up being part of the value, so `sort` sorts `b` and `a\n` in your example, `b`, `a`, and `c\n` in my version. `sort -z` uses null-separated strings for input and output.

Comment: It's in the info page: _'--zero-terminated’    Delimit items with a zero byte rather than a newline (ASCII LF).  I.e., treat input as items separated by ASCII NUL and terminate output items with ASCII NUL._

Comment: I will never ever remember to check both info and manual pages.  Sigh.  Also, tested with `find -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 cat` and everything was ducky!

Comment: @DopeGhoti on BSD? So that means `sort -z` works the same way whether it’s BSD or GNU ;-).